# Netdata - all custom collectors disappeared from the dashboard

Tags: raspberry-pi, netdata

I'm running native netdata on an RPi 3, [with a few custom python collectors to monitor my local network](https://www.devsbedevin.net/devs-be-monitoring-home-network-with-raspberry-pi-and-netdata/).

It seems that a recent update has made all of my collectors disappear from the dashboard. Nothing strange is found in any of the netdata logs.

My current installation: v1.39.0-89-nightly, installed from apt, set to auto-update, on an RPi 3 running bullseye.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that starting from netdata v1.39.0, all external collectors were split out to dedicated packages. [Because of reasons](https://blog.netdata.cloud/split-plugin-packages/).

On an apt based installation, you simply need to install all of them manually:

```
apt-cache depends netdata | \
awk '/Recommends:/ {system("sudo apt-get install "$2"; sudo apt-mark auto "$2)}'
```

And then restart the service:

```
sudo systemctl restart netdata
```

For other installations, check out this netdata blog post: https://blog.netdata.cloud/split-plugin-packages/